# Taxonomy child terms as Select options in CCK form

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary with parent-child terms. Every user is linked to a parent term in their profile field. And, I have CCK that the users fill in.

I need to add a Select Field with options as Child terms of a parent term that the User is linked to. (and save as term ref preferably)
How do I achieve this?

```
Vocabulary: "Sites"
ONE
 -a
 -b
 -c
TWO
 -d
 -e
THREE
 -f
 -g

User1 => profile field term ref => "ONE"
User2 => profile field term ref => "TWO"

CCK type: "Study"
node/add/study  =>  select field (term ref) => "Select Site"
for User1 => Select site options => a, b, c
for User2 => Select site options => d, e
```

Comment: For this you can add a term reference field and use the full vocab. Then you will need to do a form alter hook in one of your custom module and filter out options based on logged in user.

Comment: @Bharat, this solved my problem, thanks for the help! If you can add this as answer, I will be able to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can add a term reference field and use the full vocab. Then you will need to do a form alter hook in one of your custom module and filter out options based on logged in user.